# Como fazer múltiplos replaces de máscara por campo de tabela com T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, tsql, replace

Estou realizando replaces de alguns textos (Máscara) de um campo de uma tabela temporária. Estou substituindo onde há o texto procurado por um campo de outras tabelas.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * INTO #TEMP_COMPL_L FROM TB_CONTRATO WHERE IDCAR_CON = 1
ALTER TABLE #TEMP_COMPL_L ADD COMPL_TMP VARCHAR(1500)

UPDATE #TEMP_COMPL_L set COMPL_TMP = '#PRINOME#, URGENTE: Va a sua loja no dia #DATA# e procure o Gerente #NOMEGERENTE#.'

-- INSERIR DADOS DAS MÁSCARAS AQUI
UPDATE #TEMP_COMPL_L SET COMPL_TMP = 
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(COMPL_TMP,
    '#PRINOME#',LEFT(NOME_CLI, CHARINDEX(' ',NOME_CLI)-1))
    ,'#NOMEGERENTE#',ISNULL(CONTT_LOJ,''))
    ,'#DATA#',CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103)
    )
FROM #TEMP_COMPL_L INNER JOIN TB_CLIENTE ON IDCLI_CON = IDCLI_CLI
LEFT JOIN TB_LOJA ON IDLOJ_CON = IDLOJ_LOJ
```

Dessa forma funciona perfeitamente, porém, vou precisar fazer isso para mais de 20 máscaras possíveis informada pelo cliente, pegando qual é a máscara e dando um replace para o valor do campo correspondente da tabela LOJA e CLIENTE.

Há uma maneira de deixar com uma performance melhor e visivelmente legível, pois vários replaces ficará muito confuso, além de ter um limite de replaces de uma só vez.